# uncaught module cordova/plugin/smsinboxplugin not found (PhoneGap)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using Phonegap [Phonegap-SMS-reception-plugin](https://github.com/Pyo25/Phonegap-SMS-reception-plugin) first time and faceing some problem while running the app.
I have placed SmsInboxPlugin.java and SmsReciever.java inside src package org.apache.cordova.plugin .
Placed SmsInboxPlugin.js in assets/www folder.

Inside `config.xml`

```
<plugin name="SmsInboxPlugin" value="org.apache.cordova.plugin.SmsInboxPlugin"/>
```

Inside `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PhoneGap SMS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Testing SMS Feature in Phonegap</h1>
    <button id="start" onclick="start();">Start Receiving</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      console.log("Checkin to javascript");
      var smsInboxPlugin = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/smsinboxplugin");
      console.log("smsInboxPlugin" + smsInboxPlugin);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have called this `index.html` from `MainActivity.java` extending `DroidGap` by saying `super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")`.

if any body can explain which path we have to mention in argument to `require()`, either .java path or .js path.